# Eror: Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using:

rails 4.2.1;

ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32];

spree 3.0.1

database: MySQL

After installing spree success, I let it run, then it appears above error.I've used: bundle exec rake test:prepare, bundle exec rake db:migrate it show 
[image]

when I run this command: bundle exec rake db:migrate:reset, the error appears:
[image]

When I install Spree and use SQLite, it runs fine. But I don't want to use the SQLite database in my web application.

**UPDATE**

20150522034041_rename_permalink_to_slug_for_products.spree.rb file

```
# This migration comes from spree (originally 20140106224208)
class RenamePermalinkToSlugForProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :spree_products, :permalink, :slug
  end
end
```

I don't think Migrations file wrong because it worked well on SQLite

Comment: Can you post the migration files where this error comes ?

Comment: Thank @CaffeineCoder I have added migration files where the error comes

Comment: Well , this issue is arising because the rename migration loads earlier than the actual migration , hence it's not getting the actual field . Quite strange though . Have you tried with postgresql db ?

Comment: Thanks for reply @CaffeineCoder. as required, I have to use MySQL. do you know how to solve this error?

Comment: I can try , can you post the spree_product migration please

Comment: @CaffeineCoder because the migration file too long to post on here, so you can see it at. https://github.com/spree/spree_base_1_3/blob/master/db/migrate/20130107124429_spree_one_two.spree.rb
Thanks.

Comment: ok , can you just comment the migration contents for now ? The rename one ? Do a rake db:drop and migrate again after that